# Number of occurrences of subgraphs as a unique identifier

Tags: graph-theory, subgraph

Given $q \in \mathbb{N}$, let $B_q$ be a sequence of all (non isomorphic) connected graphs with at most $q$ vertices. Now for a given connected graph $G$, lets define signature of $G$ ($sig_q(G)$) as an integer-valued vector of length $|B_q|$ such that $sig_q(G)[i]=$ number of occurrences of graph $B_q[i]$ in $G$.

The question is: how large $q$ do we have to take so that any graph on $n$ vertices is uniquely determined by $sig_q(G)$?

I thought that it would be sufficient to take $q$ close to the diameter of $G$, but the following counter-example shows two graphs with diameter 4 that have the same $sig_4$ but are not isomorphic.

[Two non-isomorphic graphs with the same signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy6o2.png)

Comment: This sounds like a problem related to the reconstruction conjecture.  You might see if the variation involving graphs of degree smaller than n-1 has been posed. Gerhard "Suspects An Easily Proved Equivalence" Paseman, 2019.09.02.

Answer (score 3):

If you can answer this question, and prove it, you'll be famous. It is the [reconstruction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture) that has been open since 1957.

Basically, except for the trivial case $n=2$, nobody can prove that even $q=n-1$ is enough.  Lots of people have tried, though.